# Actionscript Three Asymmetric Encryption

Tags: python, actionscript, cryptography, token, encryption-asymmetric

I cant seem to find a reliable asymmetric encryption solution to secure data between a python based server application and a client over an open data channel.
I need some way for my client to prevent a man in the middle attack over an open data channel, my current exchange has me sending my clients a token they use to verify they are talking to my server application by checking the token is valid with a php script on my site.
This is far from ideal and could easily be compromised by waiting to be sent the token and passing it off to another user.
I have tried as3crypto's rsa encryption but it is an old implementation that is not supported by many libraries as well as having a known vulnerability.
I would really like a solution that lets me hard code public/private keys into both the client and server to prevent something like this from happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research I have decided to code the part of rsa I need from scratch.
I found some python code that will generate raw integer keys of any length and looked up how the rsa algorithm works.

T^P = X (mod R) to encrypt

X^Q = T (mod R) to decrypt

Where T is the starting data, X is the ending data, P is the public half of the key, Q is the private half of the key, and R is the shared part of the key (all integers).

Data will have a nonice whenever possible to prevent replay attacks and the message as a whole will be converted to a long integer to prevent traditional bit by bit cryptanalysis.

Answer (score 0):

Since decompiling swf content is not a major problem for experienced hackers, I would strongly advise against hardcoding keys.  Have you thought about using SSL at all?

Answer (score 0):

Hardcoding they public keys won't help you, if someone really plans an attack, because the SWF itself is transfered over an unsafe channel, thus the keys can be exchanged just as if they were transmitted individually.

There is basically **nothing** you can do to prevent man in the middle attacks, you can only make them harder. I think HTTPS is about the best you can get and it's also a fairly easy solution.

Comment: so there is no way to encrypt data on the client that only the server can read? And visa versa?

Comment: @Jordan: Security is always about making things harder, not impossible. Even if you had a secure way to exchange public keys for RSA, RSA in itself is not *impossible* to crack, only very time intense. Imho using HTTPS is the best you can do, because it uses the browser implementation, which is about as good as it gets unless you can provide a secure channel otherwise.

Comment: @back2dos even https has been beaten, but if you noticed I am doing this over what must be an insecure channel (think irc). If I use a long enough RSA key it accomplishes its purpose. After doing some research I see that the core of RSA is really easy to code, I will probably end up hardcodeing the RSA algorithem with my public key (1024 bit) so the clients can securely send me data (like login info). I know this opens up a replay attack so I plan on wrapping it like this ((i want to log in) (authkey 123456789) (enc (login as X pass Y ip Z auth 123456789) ) (login success)). Any problems?

Comment: @Jordan: Yes, as I said: The SWF is transmitted over an insecure channel. If the key is embedded within the SWF, the attacker can intercept it, replace it and serve an SWF with a different key, thus permitting MITM.

Comment: ahh I see. I wasn't even thinking that route. That's an acceptable risk, as it is an order of magnitude harder to pull off then the man in the middle vulnerability I was originally talking about. That man in the middle requires some form of network or server access that if I cover my bases I really don't need to worry about (cant stop everything) and if someone really does have that access man in the middle isn't your only concern ;)

Comment: @Jordan: You do not seem to understand: There is **no** difference between embedding the key in an SWF or just exchanging it separately. They are equally vulnerable to man in the middle attacks.

Comment: @back2dos, you sure you understand the situation I am talking about? I am exchanging data over an open channel (someone elses channel for that matter), currently someone can trick my application (a moderation system for an interactive game over this channel) by forwarding data between NormalUser and ServerUser (my server applications user representation in the room) and modifying data in the middle or stealing it. They take exactly what my app sends and sends it to the client to make it think HackingUser is the application and go from there. I do believe this fixes my original issue.

Comment: @Jordan: No, it doesn't. You exchange the client part of the application over that channel. HackingUser can intercept and modify it. With libraries such as hxformat you can easily create a programm, that will replace the key in realtime. Simply imagine your client would be running on JavaScript instead of FlashPlayer and you had the key hard coded (i.e. sent in plain text). Just flash content is not distributed it its source form, it doesn't mean it is much harder to modify.

Comment: @back2dos no I do not exchange the client part of that information over that channel, you are showing more and more you misunderstand the circumstances. The current man in the middle attack requires NO local network access, no swf modifying, and as such is MUCH easier then the mitm you are talking about. If someone has access to the victims network, there isnt CRAP I can do, at that point its the victims problem not mine. Currently a bot can harvest usernames/passwords with this mitm. I hope you can see we are talking about 2 different attacks here.

Comment: @Jordan: Ok, so how does the SWF get to the client?

Comment: @back2dos do you still see problem with encrypting data on the client in only a way my server can read to prevent mass exploitation of the system by forwarding data between Victimuser and Serveruser in what is essentially a chat room with an applications server bot in it? The swf is external and on a totally different channel. If you do raise an issue please be sure it has an answer. I realize that you can modify apps and keys and such over http (even https) but there isnt a great solution to that problem and its not MY problem until all my users get their private networks hacked.

Comment: @back2dos its transmitted like most swf's over http

Comment: @Jordan: Ok, I think, I understand your problem now. So you do have a *sufficiently* secure channel to load the client and a *suffictiently* secure channel to an introduction service (i.e. your php script), that both the python server and the flash client can access?

Comment: @back2dos yes but the introduction service token is passed off to the client over the known insecure channel that the chat room is run off of (not really chat but for simplifications sake). This can lead to Hacker passing off the token the bot gave him to Victim causing Victim to send data that should be directly sent to the Server_user to Hacker instead and thats how the mitm stats. But thats OK, all he can do is forward unmodified data if I protect against eavesdropping, data modifying, and replay attacks.